# How to customize a “MsgBox” control in Visual Basic 6

Tags: msgbox

How to use msgbox to display an error message that the type of data given to the program is different from the type of data that is specified when defining the variable for that?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

You need to add a try/catch block around the code where this variable is entered, then catch a TypeMismatch exception, and output your message when it is thrown.